# JavaScript / jQuery loader math question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, load

I think I'm having a brain fart here... Also, please note, the `setTimeout` and the hardcoded `6` is just there for testing out the animation right now. It'll end up being in a `.load()` and do a count on the images. Anyways this code:

```
var imagesLoaded = 0;

var loader = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      if(imagesLoaded < 6){
        imagesLoaded++;
        console.log($('.'+settings.loaderClass).width()/imagesLoaded+'px')
        loader();
      }
  },500)
}

loader();
```

Almost works, but the math is the issue. That goes backwards. Fine, so I reverse it like:

```
console.log(imagesLoaded/$('.'+settings.loaderClass).width()+'px')
```

but then I get:

```
0.0026041666666666665px
0.005208333333333333px
0.0078125px
0.010416666666666666px
0.013020833333333334px
0.015625px
```

And, obviously, that wouldn't work.

Whats the math i have to do? Basically the markup is simply:

```
<div class="loader">
   <div class="loaderBar"></div>
</div>
```

and im just increasing the width of the `.loaderBar`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console.log(($('.'+settings.loaderClass).width()*imagesLoaded/6) +'px')

Where the 6 is the total number of images loaded, which is probably a variable in your case. The sequence then goes WIDTH * 0/6, WIDTH * 1/6, WIDTH * 2/6 ... and you might want to include a phase where you have WIDTH * 6/6 if you need to show 100% completion.

Answer (score 3):

You need (imagesLoaded / totalImages) * loaderWidth.